# JQuery unmerge table rows and populate with values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have HTML table with merged rows. I need to unmerge them and fill with related values.

```
|column 1|column 2|column 3|column 4|column 5|column 6|
-------------------------------------------------------
|        |  Green |apples  |        |  cow   |   23   |
         ------------------         -------------------
|  John  |  Red   |Oranges |February|  lion  |   18   |
         ------------------         -------------------
|        |        |apples  |        |        |   45   |
---------         ------------------         ----------
|        |  Blue  |oranges | April  |  cow   |   23   |
                  ------------------         ----------
|  Mary  |        |        |  May   |        |   49   |
          --------         ----------------------------
|        |  green | apples |  June  |  cat   |   67   |
          --------         ----------------------------
|        |  red   |        |  July  |  mouse |   32   |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

At the end is should look like this:

```
|column 1|column 2|column 3|column 4|column 5|column 6|
-------------------------------------------------------
|  John  |  Green |apples  |February|  cow   |   23   |
-------------------------------------------------------
|  John  |  Red   |Oranges |February|  lion  |   18   |
-------------------------------------------------------
|  John  |  Blue  |apples  |February|  cow   |   45   |
-------------------------------------------------------
|  Mary  |  Blue  |oranges |  April |  cow   |   23   |
-------------------------------------------------------
|  Mary  |  Blue  |apples  |   May  |  dog   |   49   |
-------------------------------------------------------
|  Mary  |  green |apples  |  June  |  cat   |   67   |
-------------------------------------------------------
|  Mary  |  red   |apples  |  June  |  mouse |   32   |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

I have no idea how to do this.

```css
table, td{
  border:1px solid grey;
  margin:2em
}

td {
  padding: 1em;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>column 1</td>
<td>column 2</td>
<td>column 3</td>
<td>column 4</td>
<td>column 5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">John</td>
<td>green</td>
<td>apples</td>
<td rowspan="2">February</td>
<td>cow</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>red</td>
<td>oranges</td>
<td>lion</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">Mary</td>
<td>blue</td>
<td rowspan="2">meat</td>
<td rowspan="2">May</td>
<td>dog</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>white</td>
<td>cat</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you put related code so that it will be better to understand

Comment: @NitinDaddikar I posted simple code,

Comment: you can remove the rowspan then it ll convert to single row. like https://jsfiddle.net/1382gus9/

Answer (score 1):

Here's is one approach:

1. Initialize an array of the same size as the target table.
2. Run through the row of the existing table and populate the array
3. Use the resulting array to rebuild the desired table

See steps 1 & 2 (& 3) in demo below:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $table = $('table tbody');
  let rows = $table.find('tr').length;
  let columns = $table.find('tr').not(':has(td[rowspan]').first().find('td').length;
  let table = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
    table[j] = [];
    for (let l = 0; l < columns; l++) {
      table[j][l] = null;
    }
  }
  let row = 0;
  $('tr').each(function() {
    let column = 0;
    $('td', this).each(function() {
      while(table[row][column]) {
        column++;
      }
      table[row][column] = $(this).text();
      if ($(this).is('[rowspan]')) {
        for (let i = 0; i < +$(this).attr('rowspan') - 1; i++) {
          let thisrow = row+i+1;
          table[thisrow][column] = $(this).text();
        }
      }
      column++;
    });
    row++;
  });
  
  //step 3
  //empty the table
  $table.empty();
  //rebuild the table
  for (let k = 0; k < table.length; k++) {
    $table.append( 
      $('<tr/>').append(
        table[k].map(col => $('<td/>').text( col ))
      )
    );
  }
});
```

```css
table, td{
  border:1px solid grey;
  margin:2em
}

td {
  padding: 1em;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>column 1</td>
<td>column 2</td>
<td>column 3</td>
<td>column 4</td>
<td>column 5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">John</td>
<td>green</td>
<td>apples</td>
<td rowspan="2">February</td>
<td>cow</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>red</td>
<td>oranges</td>
<td>lion</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">Mary</td>
<td>blue</td>
<td rowspan="2">meat</td>
<td rowspan="2">May</td>
<td>dog</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>white</td>
<td>cat</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is working on simple table, but table I'm working on is more complicated and I'm looking more generic solution. Thank You for time.

Comment: We'r always glad to help. We do our best to guide you in the right direction. If the answer provided is not satisfactory, please feel free to rephrase your  question in this or a new post.